# Is it possible to create a question based for r-exams, based on Venn diagrams code from TikZ?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, tikz, r-exams

I'm trying to create a question in RMarkdown, using `r-exams`, based on the Venn diagrams package from TikZ https://www.ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram. I can't get it to work properly.

Here part of my code:

```
grafika01<-'
    \\begin{tikzpicture}
        \\begin{venndiagram3sets}
    \\fillNotABC
\\end{venndiagram3sets}
\\end{tikzpicture}
```

'

What's more,

````
```{r grafica01, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
include_tikz(grafika01, name = "grafiko1", markup = "markdown",format = typ,library = 
c("arrows"),packages = 
c("booktabs","tikz","pgfplots","venndiagram","calc","babel","xkeyval","etoolbox"),
width = "7cm")
```
````

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Note: This is really more about combining `{tikz}` and `{venndiagram}` and does not have much to do with R/exams.)*

If you want to put a `{venndiagram3sets}` into a `{tikzpicture}` then you need to include it in a `\node{...};`:

```
grafika01 <- '
\\begin{tikzpicture}
\\node{
\\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\\fillNotABC
\\end{venndiagram3sets}
};
\\end{tikzpicture}
'
```

And this LaTeX code can then be compiled successfully, e.g., using `include_tikz()`:

```
include_tikz(grafika01, name = "grafiko1", markup = "markdown", format = typ,
  packages = "venndiagram", width = "7cm")
```